# Use VBA to navigate a website and modify drop down box

Tags: html, excel, vba

Good Morning,

I am working a VBA project where I would like to access an internal company, login required, web site and extract data from a table.  I have successfully written code that will navigate to the correct website, and then modify a drop down box value from "All Transactions" to "Running Record".  The problem I have is that I cannot not get the data in the table to refresh once the drop down box is updated.  On the website, next to the drop down field, is a "Go" hyperlink.  Whenever I try to activate the link, using vba,  it resets the drop down and I don't get the data displayed that I want.

I was able to find a similar post where a user explained that the issue was related to the site being secured and that a .FireEvent would need to be used.  Although the concept made sense to me implementation was another story.  The biggest difference between my situation and the other's was that when his drop down box was changed it would activate the event.  In my case there is a seperate ID, the "Go" hyperlink I mentioned above, that needs to be activated once the drop down value is entered.

Below is a portion of the HTML code where drop down box options are located as well as the "GO" hyperlink.

```
<select name="classList" onchange="selectClass(this);"><option class=tblrow2 value="All" selected=selected>All Schedules</option>

                    <option value="A"  >
                        Transactions-Financial
                    </option>


                    <option value="N"  >
                        Transactions-Non-Financial
                    </option>


                    <option value="RB"  >
                        Running Balance
                    </option></select>
             <input type="hidden" name="classindx" id = "classindx" value="" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onClick="submitTransForm()">&nbsp;Go&nbsp;</a>
```

This is a portion of my code that modifies the dropdown box value.

```
'try to get form by ID
   Set frm = ie.Document.getElementByID("myFormID")

   'try to get form by name
   If frm Is Nothing Then Set frm = ie.Document.getElementsByName("facilityFeeRepayForm").Item(0)

        'Set ieButton = ie.Document.getElementById("classindx") Here I tried to treat the Go hyperlink like a button but that didn't work either.  

   If frm Is Nothing Then

   Else
      ie.Visible = True
      For Each element In frm.elements
         On Error Resume Next
         Select Case element.Name
            Case "classList": element.Value = "RB"
            ie.getElementByID("classindx").FireEvent("onClick") 'nothing happens with this code

   While ie.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

         End Select
      Next
   End If
```

I would appreciate any help you can offer.

Thank you,
John

Comment: The click event is on the link: you're trying to fire it on a hidden form field.

Comment: also the unclick event is case sensitive and the c needs to be lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of clicking the link, try this:

```
ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript "submitTransForm()", "JavaScript"
```

Comment: Tim, I received a syntax error when I ran this code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry - try without the parentheses

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Now I just need to figure out the best way to extract the data.  Thanks Tim.